# How to completely uninstall git from Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, git, software-uninstall

About 6 months ago I tried installing git and ended up botching the install/configuration. I was then called away to another project and no longer needed to use git. I'm back to the project now, and would like to reinstall git completely from scratch. So I ask:

**How do I completely uninstall git from my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 machine**?

When I run `which git` I get:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove git
```

Answer (score 4):

Your personal settings for your user related to git are usually stored in `~/.git` which is the `.git` folder in your `/home/$USER` folder.

Just remove `~/.gitconfig` and your settings will return to a pristine, unconfigured state.

**if you REALLY want to remove git completely and start over** which you don't really need to do ever, do the above statements to remove the `.git` folder, then do: `sudo apt-get purge git; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get install git`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling git with

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

will usually fix most installation issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue when another `git` client was installed on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS without my  with a different path :

```
PATH=/home/pradan/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am57xx-evm-06.02.00.81/linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin:...other variables...:/snap/bin
```

To remove it, the `PATH VARIABLE` needs to be changed. Changing the path can be seen in this question [How can I edit the $PATH on linux?](https://superuser.com/a/1558084/1143104)

Then, the git files in the same directory can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To remove just git package itself from Ubuntu execute on terminal:
`sudo apt-get remove git`
Uninstall git and it's dependent packages
`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove git`

from [here](https://gist.github.com/pokisin/fc4bf37a5ced0e6f7fe6e45333e37b4f)